# Quando se trata de português antigo, deve-se escrever em itálico?

Tags: ortografia, escrita

Eu preciso escrever num texto o nome do livro "Grammatica da Lingoagem Portuguesa", porém não sei se devo escrever em itálico porque é português, mas, ao mesmo tempo, é uma grafia antiga e é chamado de português moderno — o de hoje é chamado de português contemporâneo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, o itálico deve ser utilizado, pois a frase não faz mais parte da lingua portuguesa. O itálico pode ser utilizado em algumas situações, dentre elas: dar ênfase, portanto você pode utilizar sem qualquer preocupação; citar palavras estrangeiras ou incomuns¹².

Referências:

¹ http://abre.ai/pucrioitalico

² http://abre.ai/g1italico